# A four-term sequence of vector spaces is exact if and only if the intermediate map is an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, solution-verification, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

This is Proposition 25.3(i) from Tu's book on manifolds:

> The four-term sequence $0 \rightarrow A \xrightarrow{f} B \rightarrow 0$ of vector spaces is exact if and only if $f: A \rightarrow B$ is an isomorphism.

The proof is left as an exercise. This is my attempt:

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose the sequence is exact. Let $g: 0 \rightarrow A$ and $h:B \rightarrow 0$ denote the two maps not labelled in the sequence. If $b \in B$, then $b$ is in the kernel of $h$, and by exactness must also be in the image of $f$. This proves $f$ is surjective.

Now suppose $f(x) = f(y)$ for some $x, y \in A$. Then by linearity, $f(x-y) = 0$. Since $g$ is linear it must map the zero element to the zero element. Since $g$ only consists of the zero element, by exactness, the kernel of $f$ is $\{0\}$. Hence $x = y$. So $f$ is injective.

Since $f$ is linear and bijective, it must be an isomorphism.

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose $f$ is an isomorphism. Define $g$ and $h$ as above. By surjectivity, Im$(f) = B$, and since $h$ is the zero map, we have that Im$(f) = $ Ker$(h)$. By injectivity, Ker$(f) = \{0\}$. Since $g$ is required to be linear, we must have that $g$ is the zero map. Thus Im$(g) =$ Ker$(f)$.

This proves the sequence must be exact.

---

For the forward direction, is the linearity of $f, g$, and $h$ implied from the definition or must be that be proven as well? Similarly, I assumed that $g$ and $h$ must be linear when proving the converse. Is this assumption ok to make? Is my proof otherwise correct?

Comment: Your argument is fine.  Generally speaking, to talk of an exact sequence requires an abelian category and, then, it is assumed that the arrows are arrows in that category.  Here, Vector Spaces  (presumably over some fixed field $\mathbb F$) is the category and the maps are $\mathbb F$ linear.

Comment: @lulu Thank you. Maybe I should learn some category theory, it seems to help with these sort of problems.

Comment: At this level, it mostly just means that we can take a lot of structure for granted.  We're speaking about vector spaces, so in that context writing e.g. $F:V\to W$ really ought to mean a linear map without a lot of discussion.  Indeed, if you meant something else *then* you should discuss what $F$ is.  Later on, with cohomology and such, more structure can come into play.